# handling multi-select with no selection

Tags: grails

I used `grails generate-all` on my application. The `Author` view has a multi-select which allows for a number of `Book` instances:

```
<g:select multiple="true" ... />
```

However, if I edit an existing `Author` who owns 5 out of total 15 books (the multi-select shows 15 books, 5 selected), unselect all books and click save, the `Author` still keeps their 5 books. From what I can tell, no book input from the form - books property of `Author` don't get changed.

Now, I can test for this in my controller (something like this):

```
if (params?.books.size() < 1) {
     authorInstance.books = []
}
```

Is this the way to do it, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most examples I've seen use:

```
authorInstance.books.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, that a multi select list can not be emptied by default data binding, as the `params` map does not contain fields with a value of `NULL`.

To circumvent this, you can do this in your `.gsp`:

```
<g:hiddenField name="books" value="" />
<g:select multiple="true" name="books" />
```

When you post this form elements, the multi select will override the hidden field. If the multi select is empty, you will fallback to the empty string.

Not pretty, but get the job done, when you can not alter the controller action.